# MVVM and updating WPF DataGrid Layout

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, caliburn.micro

I am using MVVM via Caliburn Micro.  I have a datagrid bound to a list of view models.  I am running a process in a background thread that updates the datagrid's item viewmodels one at a time.

Everything is working great, the data grid's items update in real time as each of the item viewmodels get updated, just as you would expect.

One small problem:  When an item's view model update occurs, the datagrid's layout get mucked up.  For example, if I update an item's status from "OK" to "Oh no, something bad happened", that column get re-sized appropriately, but the subsequent columns get shrunk, obscuring the content in them.

If I refresh the entire grid, then everything get laid out appropriately.

Since I am using MVVM, I don't have access to the datagrid control itself, so I cannot use the datagrid's UpdateLayout method directly.

I could use CM's ViewAware view model, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just use the Event Aggregator to publish a refresh message. This way if you change anything the two components are still loosely coupled. It does mean a little code-behind in your view but it's a small price to pay to maintain separation of concern (ok you are introducing a tiny bit of concern from the view into the VM, but it's non-breakable)

Comment: Seems like a View-specific problem that could perfectly be resolved by View-specific Code Behind, this would not break MVVM.

Comment: do you still need help with that issue? I would maybe create a behavior for the datagrid that will enable me to invoke a refresh without and bind to a property\method of the behavior and thus not break the pattern